# Property 'x' does not exist on type (when checking if it exists)

Tags: typescript, react-native, compiler-errors

The relevant part of my current code looks like this:
(code edited from https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node)

```
  const tickets: ExpoPushTicket[] = [], receiptIds = [];

  ...

  for (const ticket of tickets) {
    if (ticket.id) {
      receiptIds.push(ticket.id);
    }
  }
```

where the types look like this (from **expo-server-sdk** library):

```
export declare type ExpoPushSuccessTicket = {
    status: 'ok';
    id: ExpoPushReceiptId;
};
export declare type ExpoPushErrorTicket = ExpoPushErrorReceipt;
export declare type ExpoPushErrorReceipt = {
    status: 'error';
    message: string;
    details?: {
        error?: 'DeviceNotRegistered' | 'InvalidCredentials' | 'MessageTooBig' | 'MessageRateExceeded';
    };
    __debug?: any;
};
export declare type ExpoPushTicket = ExpoPushSuccessTicket | ExpoPushErrorTicket;
```

The issue is `if (ticket.id)` gives `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ExpoPushTicket'`.
The purpose of the if in itself was to see if the property id existed, since it's undefined only if there is an error.
I checked to see if there were other methods and found `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` which managed to not give a compilation error on the `if` line, but the error was still there on `receiptIds.push(ticket.id)`.
What is the correct way to check if my `ticket` contains the property?
Should I import and change the type of ExpoPushTicket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `ExpoPushTicket` is a union type. Without a type guard you can only access a property if it exists on all union participants. In your case check first for a specific type using a type guard and then access the `id` field.

The [simplest solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=4&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHmA9gBQK4GcAWAlCBjCASzGAEkATKAXinWACdCA7AcwG4AoDiBRe4KOXwAbAIb1ooSLF5osAZVR4C6dABVCeANYQBNAN4cox2sFHAMALigByRFpucTUQuWvwkcnPiIkKnAF9OHiR%20QRFxSXBoDxQMTBh6ej4NbV1qGU94xOT6XAJiYGDeMKE8MQkoKRjZbKS%20fN89KENnOnMrWwh6%20kcjEwBbCFVRFghrOkZWJxMhM0JhdAB%20a1bnE27cldsAEQgAN00IADlEYFwWQjpuiHIbKAAfW1ImfdFhVwBhCSEmYEJ3uh7k8bABZYboUYQNSIRAAIUILGBtnBIzG2HMEHgBFutz6ziC-WMAH1iUIAEaoFjbURMECBYqhARlCpRaSxLypHTNDnxRTKCFc9JPXlYHIpTTczj9PCIJh0KqS3Tody1LBC4AAbQAuhkdQAaKASAp%20cjoPXa6XGABmfCgAApZfKBP80gJENbFW70ABKFpElye%200AIlcwZcTC93L9a2cxqaFHQADowPF7a7uUnXD6ZsYAv0AkA) is probably the `in` operator:

```
  for (const ticket of tickets) {
    if ("id" in ticket) {
      receiptIds.push(ticket.id);
    }
  }
```

This check narrows the union type to `ExpoPushSuccessTicket` where accessing the `id` field is legal.